# PYMC decorators keywords meaning: trace, plot

Tags: pymc

I playing around with PYMC and in a linear regression code I generated a stochastic variable via the stochastic decorator:

```
@pymc.stochastic(observed=True, trace=True)
def model(value = y_data, x_values = x_data, m = m_coef, n = n_coef, sigma = sigma):
    value_theo      = m*x_values + n
    chi_sq          = np.sum( np.square(value - value_theo) / np.square(sigma))
    log_ChiSq       = - chi_sq / 2.0
    return log_ChiSq
```

I would like to plot the evolution of log_chisq along the MCMC iterations. However, the trace for this variable seems not to be stored...

Hence my questions:

1) Where can I find the definition, or example of the meaning of the pymc decorator keywords, such as plot or trace?

2) Why is the trace of stocastic (but observed) variable not preserved as a trace?

Thanks a lot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc

#Generating some data for the model_difference y = m * x + n
m_true, n_true  = 3, 2
sigma_true      = 2
x_true          = 25 * (np.random.random(50) - 0.5)
y_true          = m_true * x_true + n_true

#Adding some scatter
x_data, y_data  = x_true, y_true
x_data, y_data  = np.random.normal(x_true, 2), np.random.normal(y_true, 2)

#Providiing estimates for priors
Np_lsf          = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 1)
m_0, n_0        = Np_lsf[0], Np_lsf[1]

#Priors
m_coef          = pymc.Normal('m_coef', m_0, 0.01)
n_coef          = pymc.Normal('n_coef', n_0, 0.01)
sigma           = pymc.Uniform('sigma', 0.0, 5.0)

#---Chi Square Moodel
@pymc.stochastic(observed=True, trace=True)
def model(value = y_data, x_values = x_data, m = m_coef, n = n_coef, sigma = sigma):
    value_theo      = m*x_values + n
    chi_sq          = np.sum( np.square(value - value_theo) / np.square(sigma))
    log_ChiSq       = - chi_sq / 2.0
    return log_ChiSq


MCMC_dict2      = dict(m_coef=m_coef, n_coef=n_coef, sigma=sigma, model=model)
M               = pymc.MCMC(MCMC_dict2)
M.sample(iter=10000, burn=100)

#Code variables
print M.variables

#MCMC ouput
print '\nInitial m, n, estimations'
print m_0, n_0

print 'Bayesian estimation Model 2' 
print M.m_coef.value, M.n_coef.value, 'with Sigma:', M.sigma.value

#Store pymc_tracers
MCMC_Traces = [M.trace('m_coef')[:], M.trace('n_coef')[:], M.trace('sigma')[:], M.trace('model')[:]]

# #Plotting regression
Fig    = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 9))  
Axis1  = Fig.add_subplot(111)
Fig.set_facecolor('w')
Axis1.plot(x_data, y_data, 'ok')
Axis1.plot(x_data, m_0 * x_data + n_0, '-', color='blue', label = 'least-squares fit')
Axis1.plot(x_data, M.m_coef.value * x_data + M.n_coef.value, '-', color='red',  label = r'$\chi^{-2}$ model')
Axis1.plot(x_data, m_true * x_data + n_true, '-', color='black',  label = r'true data model, $\sigma=$'+str(sigma_true))
Axis1.xlabel('x')
Axis1.ylabel('y')
Axis1.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass to a PyMC decorator any arguments that you would pass to a PyMC object if you were instantiating it directly. `observed`, `trace` and `plot`, for example, are all arguments that any `Stochastic` would accept. So, to see what you can pass to `@stochastic`, look at the class docstring itself.